# Multiple criteria in dynamic Excel dropdown list

Tags: excel, list, dropdown

I set up a dynamic dropdownlist using the "Name manager", which is based on criterias, with the following formula :

`=INDIRECT("'Source'!"&VLOOKUP('Reporting'!$K$11,'Source'!$BN$11:$BO$50,2,0))`

[image]

I would like to add the `"*"` hard data to show up everytime my list generates.

ie. my list generates the following data : `"Paris", "Rome", "Tokyo"`. I would like it to generate `"*", "Paris", "Rome", "Tokyo"`.

I tried using this trick in the Nama manager, but it wont work : `{=INDIRECT("'Source'!"&VLOOKUP('Reporting'!$K$11,'Source'!$BN$11:$BO$50,2,0));"*"}`.

Any idea how to deal with this issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't give us enough to work with. We need at least these 3 things: 1) please show us the data in 'Source'!$BN$11:$BO$50 (just a few rows, not all 40, and as a table we can copy, not as a screen shot); 2) tell us what is in the cell 'Reporting'!$K$11; and 3) do you want the drop down list to contain the 4 items "(asterisk)", "Paris", "Rome", "Tokyo"? (Not sure how to display the asterisk in a comment here.)

Comment: Hi @RichardCook,
I aded a couple of screenshots. Does this help you? I can always send you the file (I used anonymous data).
In the example I show, My list retrieves some fruit tastes. These tastes are generated automatically thanks to the range specified in "Table 13", column "I". I would like the list to retrieve the same list BUT ALSO the "*" item, which is not part of the "Table 13", column "K".
Is it clearer ? I can always send you the file but I could not find a way to do it on staroverflow. Is there a filehoster you would recommend ?